# i have a problem with get location in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocator

[this the code for get the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hBzT.png)

i have tried many things but nothing worked

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXun4.png)

if you asked for the yaml file thats it

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
geolocator: ^10.0.1
geocoding: ^2.1.0
firebase_core: ^2.15.1
firebase_auth: ^4.9.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.9.1
firebase_storage: ^11.2.6
image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading the geolocator documentation at https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator . You need to get the location permission before using it like the first example also shows

Comment: Where do you get location permissions? In the geolocator package there are some methods to check and request location permission.
`Geolocator.checkPermission()`, `Geolocator.requestPermission()`, `Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled().`

Answer (score 0):

- based on this package `geolocator` here sample below code

```
  static Future<Position?> determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // Location services are not enabled don't continue
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
        return null;
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return null;
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```

and check if get Position location

```
  Position? position = await determinePosition();

  if (position != null) {
    LatLng latLng = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    return latLng;
  }
```